# When doing deploy of my application using spring with swagger2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic12c, swagger-2.0

When doing deploy of my application using spring with swagger2 I get the following error:

```
Message icon - Error An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.transform(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;
Message icon - Error com.google.common.base.Optional.transform(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;
```

Has anyone here been through this?

My pom.xml:

```
<!-- inicio Apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Fim apache -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- inicio eclipselink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.oracle</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- fim Eclipselink -->

    <!-- inicio javax -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- fim javax -->

    <!-- inicio spring -->

    <!-- inicio spring-security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- fim spring-security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- fim spring -->

    <!-- Para retornar objetos JAVA no formato JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- teste -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- fim tewste -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
        <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Java Email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- INICIO Swagger -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>2.7.0</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>2.7.0</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>guava</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>26.0-android</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
    <!--FIM - Swagger -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That is from guava, which you have commented out

Comment: even though I uncomment, the error persists